# Has anybody installed Brother hl-5450DN on Ubuntu 14.1?

Tags: brother

I'm on my way to a windows-free office environment. I came over a relatively longlasting printer (8000 page cartriges!) Brother hl-5450DN. Does anybody use it with Ubuntu 14.1? (It should support linux according to the manufacturer.)

Answer (score 1):

We have a Brother 2250DN. Which works well enough through the [Brother Linux Driver](http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/instruction_prn1.html?c=us_ot&lang=en&redirect=on). Some people just use the generic drivers. These work but I couldn't get toner reporting to work.

One thing to note is the page alignment was off. This seems to be echoed across a number of models and while I've no idea what causes it, the issue is easy enough to fix:

```
sudo lpadmin -p HL2250DN -o pdftops-renderer-default=pdftops
```

You just change the name of the printer there. That seems to have stuck through multiple reboots.

There is one lasting issue. I can't get the duplex setting to take from the client side. I have to log into the printer's webmin and set it there before printing. This might not affect you and even if it does, it's hardly a showstopper.

Also the "compatible" toners on Ebay (et al) are just as good and for half the price. You can even refill them yourself for even less. This is by far the cheapest printer to run I've ever owned.

Comment: I have the same printer - works fine out of the box with drivers that the printer dialog installs (HL-2250DN-series) over network and USB... duplex works fine as well. Probably something to do with copying the entry for the USB connection to the printer and changing the address to its IP address... Also HL2250DN driver doesn't work as well.

Comment: The HL-5450DN has a 2600 pages toner. The 5450 with 8000 pages would be even more economic I think. Why does the HL2250DN driver not work?

Answer (score 0):

I have installed the HL-5450DN on 14.04.

I do have one problem though.  Sometimes when I print especially after a previous job I get pages of garbage which I have to cancel to save paper.  I keep this from happening by turning off/on the printer between jobs.  This is frustrating to me.

Using the prescribed procedures on the this model by the Manufacturer.

[Manufacturer Drivers for this model](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=hl5450dn_all&os=128)